Obtain KML/KMZ route following train tracks?
I'm making some route animations where I animate a path from point A to point B on a map.  So far, I've been animating driving routes that follow roads, and my workflow is the following:

Use Google My Maps to add driving directions from point A to point B
Use the "Export to KML/KMZ" function of Google My Maps to get a KMZ file containing the driving route
Loading the KMZ file into QGIS
Exporting the route as an SVG file, together with an appropriate PNG base map
Loading the SVG and PNG files into my animation software to generate a video

I would now like to animate a route following a train line (specifically it's between two stations on the Amtrak Empire Service, though I don't think this changes anything).  However, Google My Maps doesn't support train routes, and it isn't possible to export transit directions using regular Google Maps.
Is there any alternative way (not necessarily from Google) where I can export a KMZ/KML path between two train stations that snaps to the train tracks?
